# jQuery-ui: weird shake effect

Tags: jquery

I have a weird problem with the jQuery-UI shake effect. I want to change the distance but now its doing weid stuff:
When the distance is 16;

http://jsfiddle.net/9My7t/

When I set the distance to default (20) is also does the same thing.

Code:

```
$( "#registerButton" ).click(function() {
    $( "#register" ).find( "input" ).each(function() {
        if($( this ).val().trim() == "") {
            $( this ).effect( "shake", "left", 16);
        }
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="message">
    <div id="register">
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" />
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="**********" />
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="**********" />
        <input type="email" id="username" placeholder="Emailadres" />
        <button id="registerButton">Registreer</button>
        <p>Ik ga akkoord met <br /> de <a href="#">algemene voorwaarden</a></p><input type="checkbox" id="remeberme" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When you remove the 16:

```
( this ).effect( "shake", "left");
```

Now its working fine.

Why is the shake effect doing weird when I add the distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

http://jsfiddle.net/9My7t/4/

```
$("#registerButton").click(function () {
    $("#register").find("input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
            $(this).effect("shake", {distance: 16});
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#registerButton").click(function () {
    $("#register").find("input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
            $(this).effect( "shake", 
          {direction:"left", times:4}, 1000 );
        }
    })
});
```

**selector.effect( "shake", {arguments}, speed );**

Here is the description of all the arguments:

times: Times to shake. Default is 3.

distance:Distance to shake. Default is 20.

direction:The direction of the effect. Can be "up", "down", "left", "right". Default is "left"

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9My7t/2/